# Scala - Automatic Iterator inside pattern match

Tags: scala

I have Array Data like this : `[("Bob",5),("Andy",10),("Jim",7),...(x,y)]`.

How to do pattern matching in Scala? so they will match automatically based on Array Data that i have provided (instead of define "**Case**" one by one)

i mean dont like this, *pseudocode* :

```
val x = y.match {
 case "Bob"  => get and print Bob's Score
 case "Andy" => get and print Andy's Score
..
}
```

but

```
val x = y.match {
 case automatically defined by given Array => print each'score
}
```

Any Idea ? thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't "cross-tag". This is a scala only question, so dont put a java tag on it!

Comment: @GhostCat i've removed it

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
val xs = Array( ("Bob",5),("Andy",10),("Jim",7) )

for ( (name,n) <- xs ) println(s"$name scores $n")
```

and also

```
 xs.foreach { t => println(s"{t._1} scores ${t._2}") }
 xs.foreach { t => println(t._1 + " scores " + t._2) }
 xs.foreach(println)
```

A simple way to print the contents of `xs`,

```
println( xs.mkString(",") )
```

where `mkString` creates a string out of `xs` and separates each item by a comma.

---

**Miscellany notes**

To illustrate pattern matching on Scala `Array`, consider

```
val x = xs match {
  case Array( t @ ("Bob", _), _*) => println("xs starts with " + t._1)
  case Array()                    => println("xs is empty")
  case _                          => println("xs does not start with Bob")
}
```

In the first case we extract the first tuple, and neglect the rest. In the first tuple we match against string `"Bob"` and neglect the second item. Moreover, we bind the first tuple to tag `t`, which is used in the printing where we refer to its first item.

The second case means *every other case not covered*.

Comment: I think this is not addressing the question, which is how to print each score. In other words, the OP wants `map` (or possibly `collect`) and a destructuring-pattern-match to extract name and score?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Definite

Answer (score 0):

If printing and storing results in an array is your main concern than the following will work well:

```
 val ls = Array(("Bob",5),("Andy",10),("Jim",7)) 
 ls.map({case (x,y) => println(y); y}) // print and store the score in an array
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit confused about the question however if you just wish to print all the data in the array i would go about it doing this:

```
val list = Array(("Foo",3),("Tom",3))
list.foreach{
  case (name,score) =>
    println(s"$name scored $score")

}
//output:
//Foo scored 3
//Tom scored 3
```